# Block site on a PC logged into a domain and using a proxy

Tags: proxy, domain, blocking, web-filtering

I read lot of posts related with blocking sites. Most of the posts says to edit `hosts` file. I know it is a good method. But this one is not working for me.

Can you guess what is the issue by analyzing the following details,

My PC is joined to a domain and using proxy settings, and the logged in user having administrator privileges.

After reading some answers, I did the following

**Changed the `hosts` file to have**

```
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1   www.facebook.com
```

Added `no proxy` for facebook,
[image]

Still, it is not working. Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hosts file won't work when using a proxy, as dns lookup is done on the proxy.
You might manage to exclude the site from being proxied in browser settings and then use the hosts file.

This does sound a bit backwards though - the proxy is the place to do this.

Comment: Can you please see the updated question ?

Comment: Suggest you put "www.facebook." in the do-not-proxy, though IE is notoriously bad at obeying these, make sure you restart the browser.

Comment: You really are on a sticky wicket here BTW - why is it you can't do this at the proxy, or worst case put in an intermediate proxy?

Comment: yes. Its OK when I write www.facebook.com